# How to send data from laravel route to controller function?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I've a laravel route

`Route::get('/find/mobiles','SearchController@byCategory');`

I want send values to `byCategory` method from the route file, something like `$category='mobile' or $category = 'television'`

I'm unable to find any way to do it.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing. have you read this? I think it will help you

Comment: i'm unable to find the solution, I'm not using callback where i can pass parameters!

Comment: Pass it to the controller function (byCategory) that will handle your request

Comment: @Andreas how? can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
Route::get('find/{category}, 'SearchController@byCategory');
```

Controller:

```
Public function byCategory($category){
  ... $category is whatever is passed from the route ...
}
```